# What is the difference between App Store Connect and iTunes Connect app?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, developer-program

I have two apps installed on my iPhone:

- [App Store Connect](https://itunes.apple.com/app/app-store-connect/id1234793120)

and

- [iTunes Connect](https://itunes.apple.com/app/itunes-connect/id376771144)

What is the difference between these two apps? Both provide analytics for my apps.

- For some weird reason, iTunes Connect doesn't seem to be searchable in the iOS App Store.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

iTunes Connect is the marketing name for the originally released, Web based tool to manage app distribution on the App Store (iOS) and Mac App Store.

In June 2018, Apple rebranded **iTunes Connect** to **App Store Connect** and provided it as a separate tool:

- [Introducing App Store Connect](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=06042018)

[iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) is now intended to be used by content creators and distributors to manage media distributed via iTunes Store such as music, films, TV programmes and books, while [App Store Connect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login) is intended solely to manage app distribution for iOS (and by extension watchOS and tvOS) and macOS.

The separate iOS apps you see on your iPhone are focused on individual tools. You are able to see the app analytics in iTunes Connect apps as it was originally/previously used to manage app distribution.

This may remain so, till Apple completes transition to App Store Connect (or upto Apple's discretion).

Apple removes certain apps from search listing, (while still keeping them available on the App Store) while making transitions. You can still access the iTunes Connect app in the App Store using [this link](https://itunes.apple.com/app/itunes-connect/id376771144) on your iPhone.

Comment: Simply explained. :)

Answer (score 2):

iTunes Connect has been rebranded to App Store Connect.

See https://9to5mac.com/2018/06/06/app-store-connect-rebrand/.

> For app developers and their teams, iTunes Connect is now called App Store Connect. And with the new App Store Connect app, it’s even easier to manage your apps, view trends, respond to reviews, and reply to active Resolution Center issues, all on your iOS device. You can also receive push notifications for changes in your app status and new customer reviews.